# Write an SQL Statement

Tags: mysql

I have got a table called "DELIVERY" and it has attributes as following: DELIVERYID,    SHOP ID,    APPLIANCEID,    MODELID,    WHOLESALERID,   DELIVERY DATE,  QUANTITY,   PRICE.

DELIVERYID is its primary key.
SHOP ID,    APPLIANCEID,    MODELID,    WHOLESALERID are its foreign keys.

The question is to write an SQL Statement that displays delivery details -id, city and state the delivery is scheduled for and the total cost of the delivery, if the date of delivery is on or after 20th of August, 2015

Can someone explain the question to me? I don't understand what is "state the delivery is scheduled for”.
Also how can I get the total cost of the delivery.

Comment: "city" and "state" aren't captured in your data.  You can't query those values.  Unless it's in a table you haven't seen fit to share with us.  "Total cost" probably has something to do with the `PRICE` column, possibly combined with the `QUANTITY` column.

Comment: "state" is a political unit.  It is often used in the United States (and certain other countries) to identify a location as part of an address.  The use of "city" and "state" suggests that there is another table (probably of addresses) that is not included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select d.DELIVERYID, d.PRICE, s.CITY, s.STATE, d.DELIVERYDATE
from DELIVERY d
join SHOP s on s.SHOPID = d.SHOPID
where d.DELIVERYDATE >= '2015-08-20'`

This answer is assuming the location information is in the SHOP entity

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(COST FIELD), DELIVERYID, (OTHERS)
FROM DELIVERY D
JOIN (TABLE) T1 ON D.FOREIGNKEY = T1.PRIMARYKEY
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY DELIVERYID, (OTHERS) (GROUP NON FUNCTION )
```